# can't import THREEjs OBJloader in NUXT

Tags: three.js, nuxt.js

i've created project in NUXT with THREEjs. [eromulon.pro](http://eromulon.pro)
And i can't understand, how to import obj and mtl loaders in nuxt. Here my code:

```
import * as OBJLoader from '@/lib/OBJLoader';
import * as MTLLoader from '@/lib/MTLLoader';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import {TweenMax} from 'gsap';

let loader_1 = new THREE.OBJLoader();
let loader_2 = new THREE.MTLLoader();
let OrbitControls = require('three-orbit-controls')(THREE);
export default{
  data(){
  return {

}
},
watch: {

},
mounted(){
console.clear();
//VARIABLES
let canvas = document.getElementById('myscene');
let width = window.innerWidth;
let height = window.innerHeight;
var fov = 45;
var near = 1;
var far = 8000;
var pos_x = 1800;
var pos_y = 500;
var pos_z = 1800;
var color = 0x000000;
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2(), INTERSECTED;
//VARIABLES_END
//SCENE_GROUP_CAMERA
let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let group = new THREE.Group();  
scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2( 0x000104, 0.0000675 );
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, width / height, near, far);
    camera.position.set(pos_x, pos_y, pos_z);
```

etc..

Here error code:

```
THREE is not defined
```

in OBJLoader.js.
I've included OBJLoader.js and MTLLoader.js in /lib directory. How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add `three` to your modules in your `nuxt.config.js`:

```
// Build configuration
build: {
    vendor: [
        'three',
    ],

// ...rest of file
```